# Структура для мультирегионального сайта

Tags: php, laravel, seo, веб-сайт

Как лучше сделать сайт, который будет доступен в разных странах с разной информацией? Лучше сделать поддомены для разных стран или как-то в одном проекте с разными таблицами для разных стран? Например вот stackoverflow на русском через поддомен реализован.

Comment: Достаточно поддоменов. Таблицы одни и те же. Просто локализированные данные будут лежать где-то для разных языков. Например тупо файл в папке с массивом с перечисленными переводами UI

Comment: Но на вариант с поддоменами нужен wildcard сертификат, я бы отдал предпочтение ссылке ( site.ru/en/index ). И поисковиками будет охотнее индексироваться.